# Migrating users from one google add-on to another

Tags: add-on, google-apps-script-addon

I have developed a google add-on and somehow, somewhere along the line it got copied and both are published, so now I have two identical google add-ons each with their own users. As this is not an ideal situation, is there any way to migrate users from one to the other? Or can I at least get a message to the users of one that says they should switch to the other before I delete it? Thanks in advance.